# OpenLDAP - ACL "set" notation not matching properly

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I've got to set up an externally-anonymous accessible LDAP directory on an Ubuntu 12.04 Server, and I want to keep authentication and internal data in a different subtree.

Example of the LDAP layout

```
dc=example.com,dc=com
    organizationUnit: ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com
        organizationUnit: ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com
            inetOrgPerson: cn=user1,ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com
            inetOrgPerson: cn=user2,ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com
        organizationUnit: ou=group2,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com

    organizationUnit: ou=group_auth,dc=example,dc=com
         account: uid=group1,password=XXX,ou=group_auth,dc=example,dc=com
```

The idea is that the uid=group1 auth will be able to add/edit ("write" basically) the entries under ou=hie_ext,ou=group1. I tried an ACL rule like this:

```
access to dn.children="ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com"
    by set="this/ou & user/uid" write
    by * none
```

When I test for write permission using slapacl, though, I get "ALLOWED" if I test against

```
"ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com"
```

but "DENIED" when I test against

```
"cn=user1,ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com"
```

which seems a bit screwy to me.

I'm probably overlooking something obvious (I'm quite green with LDAP at this point). Running the "-d trace" option to slapacl didn't help much, since I have no idea what I'm looking at. :)

**Update:**

So, while "-d trace" was a bit too spewy to be of any use to me, I've become aware of "-d acl" which will probably be much more helpful.

So if I run

```
slapacl -f slapd.conf -D"uid=group1,ou=servers,dc=example,dc=com" \ 
-b "cn=user1,ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com" "sn/write" -d acl
```

The debug output is this.

```
52d544e1 => access_allowed: write access to "cn=test,ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com" "sn" requested
52d544e1 => dn: [1] 
52d544e1 => dn: [2] ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com
52d544e1 => acl_get: [2] matched
52d544e1 => acl_get: [2] attr sn
52d544e1 => acl_mask: access to entry "cn=test,ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com", attr "sn" requested
52d544e1 => acl_mask: to all values by "uid=group1,ou=servers,dc=example,dc=com", (=0) 
52d544e1 <= check a_set_pat: this/ou & user/uid
52d544e1 => bdb_entry_get: found entry: "uid=group1,ou=servers,dc=example,dc=com"
52d544e1   ACL set[0]=group1
52d544e1   ACL set: empty
52d544e1 <= check a_dn_pat: *
52d544e1 <= acl_mask: [2] applying read(=rscxd) (stop)
52d544e1 <= acl_mask: [2] mask: read(=rscxd)
52d544e1 => slap_access_allowed: write access denied by read(=rscxd)
52d544e1 => access_allowed: no more rules
write access to sn: DENIED
```

But dropping off the record-specific cn:

```
slapacl -f slapd.conf -D"uid=group1,ou=servers,dc=example,dc=com" \ 
-b "ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com" "sn/write" -d 128
```

And it works?

```
52d545ef => access_allowed: write access to "ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com" "sn" requested
52d545ef => dn: [1] 
52d545ef => dn: [2] ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com
52d545ef => acl_get: [2] matched
52d545ef => acl_get: [2] attr sn
52d545ef => acl_mask: access to entry "ou=group1,ou=hie_ext,dc=example,dc=com", attr "sn" requested
52d545ef => acl_mask: to all values by "uid=group1,ou=servers,dc=example,dc=com", (=0) 
52d545ef <= check a_set_pat: this/ou & user/uid
52d545ef   ACL set[0]=group1
52d545ef => bdb_entry_get: found entry: "uid=group1,ou=servers,dc=example,dc=com"
52d545ef   ACL set[0]=group1
52d545ef   ACL set[0]=group1
52d545ef <= acl_mask: [1] applying write(=wrscxd) (stop)
52d545ef <= acl_mask: [1] mask: write(=wrscxd)
52d545ef => slap_access_allowed: write access granted by write(=wrscxd)
52d545ef => access_allowed: write access granted by write(=wrscxd)
write access to sn: ALLOWED
```

I'm not sure why the ACL parser would be getting a different set of values for "this/ou" between the first and second examples, which seems to be what's happening.

Comment: Finding the "-d acl" option gave me some helpful output, but no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was misunderstanding just how ACLs work. Apparently, you can't test against "inherited" attributes, which is what I was trying to do. Attributes in the DN are not part of a given object: a valuable lesson to the newbie LDAPer.

The solution was pretty simple once I figured out what I was doing wrong:

I added an "ou" element to the inetorgperson records that matched the uid of the authorization objects[0]. Things "magically" started to work.

```
by set="this/ou & user/uid" write
```

[0] Which is not the misuse of schema that it seems, as each auth account is tied to a specific unit. Promise!